# ¿como usar Image/file upload de metabox plugin de wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

soy nuevo creando temas para wordpress, pero me recomendaron usar MetaBox un plugin de wordpress para crear Metas Personalizadas de manera casi facil, bueno el problema surge cuando quiero mostrar las imagenes que coloque en mi post usando el nuevo meta generado por este plugin; cuando quiero hacer el llamodo dentro de un loop no parace el contenido solo me sale "ARRAY", pero con los campos que uso del mismo meta si me los muestra.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'mc_register_meta_boxes' );

function mc_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'mc_';
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id'         => 'standard',
        'title'      => esc_html__( 'Standard Fields', 'mc' ),
        'post_types' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'autosave'   => true,
        'fields'     => array(

            // IMAGE ADVANCED
            array(
                'name'             => esc_html__( 'Image Advanced Upload', 'mc' ),
                'id'               => "{$prefix}imgadv",
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                'max_file_uploads' => 4,
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera los coloco dentro del un loop.

```
<?php echo rwmb_meta('mc_imgadv'); ?>
```

el resultado siempre es la palabra ARRAY, y no me muestra la o las imagenes cargadas.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado el codigo correcto para que te funcione es el siguiente, yo lo hice andar en un slider sin problemas.

Lo que agregué fue la llamada por variable `$images` al metabox, luego teniendo dicha variable le hice un foreach ya que al ser múltiples archivos es posible que tenga más de uno. Por tanto, recorrí la variable y la fui imprimiendo dentro del `ul` para que quede lista para usarse en un slider por ejemplo.

Desde ya, en un código JavaScript, se debe agregar la configuracion de flexslider, pero el código también sirve para una galería común sin slider.

#### functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'mc_register_meta_boxes' );

function mc_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'mc_';
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id'         => 'standard',
        'title'      => esc_html__( 'Standard Fields', 'mc' ),
        'post_types' => 'tu-post-type',
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'autosave'   => true,
        'fields'     => array(

            // IMAGE ADVANCED
            array(
                'name'             => esc_html__( 'Image Advanced Upload', 'mc' ),
                'id'               => "{$prefix}imgadv",
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                'max_file_uploads' => 4,
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

#### Y luego en tu page template:

```
        <?php

          /*
          *  The following code creates the thumbnail navigation
          *  Flexslider
          */ 
          $images =  rwmb_meta('mc_imgadv');

          ?>  

          <span class="bars-title">
          <div id="carousel" class="flexslider" style="width: 100%;">
            <ul class="slides">
              <?php foreach( $images as $property_image ): ?>
                <li>
                  <img src="<?php echo $property_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $property_image['alt']; ?>" />
                </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </span>
```

Espero que te sirva!, funciona perfecto para tener multiple imagenes !

Comment: Hola @lucasvm19080. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. Además del código, creo que tu respuesta podría beneficiarse enormemente si describieras con tus palabras que es lo que modificaste o agregaste y cómo es que eso lograría el objetivo que busca el autor de la pregunta. Quizás una simple línea que haga referencia a esto haría toda la diferencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que agregue fue la llamada por variable $images al metabox, luego teniendo dicha variable le hice un foreach ya que al ser multple archivos es posible que tenga mas de uno, por tanto recorri la variable y la fui imprimiendo dentro del ul para que quede lista para usarse en un slider por ejemplo. Desde ya en un js debe agregar la configuracion de flexslider, pero el codigo tambien sirve para una galeria comun sin slider.

Comment: Edité tu respuesta agregando esta información. Si hay algo que quieras agregar o modificar, encontrarás el enlace a [edit] al pie de tu publicación

Comment: Perfecto gracias!, cualquier duda a disposicion.